# inline-block element in one line with text-overflow:ellipsis for long string

Tags: html, css

I want to place `inline-block` element right after `inline` element in case of need to handle very long string that has ellipsis at the end.

Example is the next:

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
.inline-text {
  display: inline;
}
.inline-red-icon {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="inline-text">
    Onelongstringonelongstringonelongstringonelongstringonelongstringonelongstring
  </div>
  <div class="inline-red-icon">
  </div>
</div>
```

It provides well-rendered results for regular-length strings in case of single-line and multi-line:
[image]

But for very long strings the `inline-block` will be moved on the next line:
[image]

Here is the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xrkpspfr/4/

I am trying to put this `inline-block` after last character, so it should be placed after ellipsis in the case with very long strings. But at this time I can think of only JS-based solution that should calculate the position of last character and make some manipulations with position of `inline-block` element. It will be even worse if you need some responsive behaviour.

Is there HTML+CSS way to put described red `inline-block` element after ellipsis without line-break before it?

**UPDATE**: There is a solution only for the case when you don't need support multi-line strings (thanks to @wadber): using `white-space:nowrap;` and `inline-block` in both cases - text block and red square. 
See the answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39409698/2474379

Comment: You can define this property in css, w`ord-wrap: break-word;`, this will break the word and move the text to next line.

Comment: Yes, but I would like to achieve this especially with `ellipsis` in case of long string

Comment: Possible solution can be [**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vivekkupadhyay/xrkpspfr/7)

Comment: @vivekkupadhyay yes, it is better that original issue's rendering, but unfortunately it interrupts a condition about an icon after last character. Thank you in any case!

Comment: Are you ok with javascript solutions ?

Comment: @SoorajChandran Yes, I am developing one right now in case if I won't find HTML+CSS solution

Answer (score 0):

Try to add this css rule to the .container:

```
white-space: nowrap;
```

Here the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xrkpspfr/10/) from [vivekkupadhyay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4763084/vivekkupadhyay)

Comment: it is the solution if we don't need multiline support. I'll update the question with link to your answer, but unfortunately I can not accept it, sorry